# Create RealmQuery programmatically in android

Tags: android, realm

Is it possible to create "realmquery" in android dynamically and pass it to realm database?

something like this

```
RealmQuery<RealmModel> query;
public Model equalTo(String fildName,String value){
    query=query.equalTo(fildName,value);

    return (Model) this;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do yourself it by wrapping your queries in utility classes, define your table names and columns as string constants and constructing your queries with the builder pattern, I suggest something like this:

```
    RealmUtils.query(Model.class).where(Model.FIELD1).equals("param1")
.And(MODEL.FIELD2).greaterThan(param2);
```

This way you can encapsulate Realm string queries and deal with strong types.